# Why special characters are not allowed in SQL table column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table and named one of the columns as `50"` the SQL accepted it but later when I right click on the table then click on "edit top 200 rows" the SQL Management studio stuck and stops working and closes.

However I still can edit other tables which don't have special characters in their column name. It sounds like the `"` is not allowed in column name? 
Any idea how can I include `"` in column name?

Comment: Does INSERT INTO/UPDATE works for that table? Which version of SSMS do you use?

Comment: Do you REALLY need to use quotes in a column name? This is a really bad idea and will give you compatibility issues.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Even better trick to annoy DBA is to use newline feed in table name. SSMS will display only first line so you could pretend that you have multiple tables with the same name. Anyway good practice is to use only alphanumeric and underscore.

Comment: Calm down there, Satan.

Comment: Not the best practice though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can include almost any character you might want by using escape characters.  So, you can have a column named `50"`.  Then you would reference it as `[50"]`.  You need to escape the name for special characters (basically, non-alphanumeric or `_`) or for reserved words (such as `from`, `select`, etc.).

That said, you do not want to have such names in your database.  The use of square braces (in SQL Server, other databases have different escape mechanisms) just clutters up queries, making them harder to write and to read.

Why does SQL have such limitations?  Well, in fact, it is a computer language and all computer languages (I think) have such limitations.  For instance, an unescaped space is not allowed in a variable name in any language I can think of (some exceptions will be noted in the comments ;).

The language itself is defined by a grammar (which is generally pretty close to the ANSI standard for SQL grammars).  The grammar defines the elements of the language and where they begin and end.  For instance, if hyphens were allowed in names then `a-b` could either be `[a-b]` or `[a] - [b]` -- an ambiguity that the parser cannot resolve.

SQL could pretty easily allow more characters in names (for instance, I don't think `~` or `?` would cause any confusion), but there really is no need.  If you really do want them, you can always escape them.

Comment: Good answer. Although for the sake of being a pedant and quoting a now-obscure language, I think AMOS (back in the days of the Commodore Amiga) used to allow unescaped spaces in variable names...?

Comment: And FORTRAN loves spaces so much it ignores them :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is so people can write reasonable validation regular expressions to stop SQL injection on user supplied column names.

While more characters are allowed then you would expect, because the characters used to do SQL injection itself aren't allowed, you can simply reject user supplied data that has them without needing to worry about checking escape characters.

Don't expect escaping a quote to work in a column name.  You can't get a semicolon into a column name, so you can't put in a column named "data;drop table students;--" :)